# HTML assets path confusion

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP project. I have a page blog.php and takes a parameter for blog id. When I pass blog id as a parameter `(i.e., http://localhost/blog?id=1)`, everything is normal but when I pass blog id as a nested path `(i.e., http://localhost/blog/1)` the scripts loaded with relative paths `<script src="./assets/js/scripts.js"></script>` are taking path as `http://localhost/blog/assets/js/scripts.js` instead of `http://localhost/assets/js/scripts.js`

Comment: Remove the `.` in the beginning of the URL's. It should be `script="/assets/..."`. If you start the URL with a `/`, the client (browser) will always read it as relative from the document root (which is where `http://localhost` is configured as). With the `.`, it will be relative from the current _URL_.

Comment: Tnakyou M. Erikson